# FileZilla: Transfer file remote server to remote server from a local computer

Tags: sftp, filezilla

Using FileZilla, is it possible to transfer files between two remote servers (say Server A and Server B) while accessing them from a local computer (say computer C)?

The way I currently do is, using Computer C, log into Server A, then run FileZilla GUI. Then transfer files using Server A as local and Server B as remote. But, running FileZilla graphically on the remote server A has been frustratingly slow.

Any suggestions to improve this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FileZilla does not allow any kind of transfer between two remote systems using any protocol.

---

SFTP protocol does not allow a direct transfer of files between two remote systems.

---

Possible workarounds are:

- If you have an SFTP access, you will typically (but not necessarily) have an SSH shell access too. So you can login to the A and initialize a direct transfer to B from shell.
- If you want to keep using GUI, you probably do not have any other option than a transfer via a local temporary copy. Some SFTP clients allow this seamlessly by drag&drop. For example *my* WinSCP. See [Can I transfer files between two remote servers with WinSCP?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_fxp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access on both machines and can install Cygwin on the Windows machine, then I recommend using `rsync`.

Here's an answer that explains how to setup rsync on Windows: [rsync from Linux to Windows over SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/1416726/rsync-from-linux-to-windows-over-ssh).