# rsync from Linux to Windows over SSH

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, rsync

Right now, I'm using SCP to copy directories from a Linux Server to a Windows 10 box. I'd like to use something like `rsync` instead, since the directory is fairly big and only a couple files change.

I have powershell running as the default shell when I SSH into the Windows box, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What would you need to know to consider the question solved?

Comment: So you need to install one of the rsync implementations for Windows on the Windows box, and then you rsync either over the native rsync protocol, or over ssh (google "rsync over ssh"). Have you tried that? What worked, what didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up installing [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe), and made sure to also install the `rsync` package. Then, I modified my `PATH` environment variable to include cygwin's `bin` directory. I was then able to call `rsync` from powershell, to confirm the installation worked.

After that, I was able to successfully use `rsync` on my Linux machine to transfer files to the Windows machine.

Comment: Could you elaborate about modifying the `PATH` variable and using powershell to call `rsync` installed on cygwin. Thanks.

Comment: @ankit7540, I installed cygwin (and selected `rsync` for install). Next, I located the `bin` directory of cygwin. I believe the default `bin` directory of cygwin is under `c:\cygwin\bin`. I added the `bin` folder location to my `PATH` environment variable. Then, I opened up powershell, typed `rsync`, and the program opened up, which means the `PATH` change worked and all was good. Maybe this link will help you: https://superuser.com/questions/27668/how-can-i-add-cygwin-bin-to-the-search-path-in-windows-xp

Comment: Thanks for the description.

Comment: After completing the instructions above, also be sure to restart the ssh server on Windows. That can be done by running `services.msc` in the command prompt, scrolling to `sshd`, righ-clicking and selecting `restart`.

Comment: Also note that you'll want to prepend `/cgydrive` to the source filepath like so: `rsync -chavzP --stats user@ip:/cygdrive/c/source/dir /target/dir`